# How to create ftp (vsftpd) in google cloud compute engine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

How to create ftp in google cloud compute engine? I can connect via SFTP without any issues, but my company is using a software to connect via FTP to download a XML file from the server. Unfortunately that software doesn't have SFTP connection facilities.

I saw lots of examples from the internet and to connect via SFTP not FTP.

Any idea's or tutorials ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found a way to do this, Please advice is there any risks.

`apt-get install vsftpd libpam-pwdfile`

`nano /etc/vsftpd.conf`

And inside the vsftpd.conf config file.

```
    # vim /etc/vsftpd.conf

    listen=YES
    listen_ipv6=NO
    anonymous_enable=NO
    local_enable=YES
    write_enable=YES
    local_umask=022
    nopriv_user=vsftpd
    chroot_local_user=YES
    allow_writeable_chroot=yes
    guest_username=vsftpd
    virtual_use_local_privs=YES
    guest_enable=YES
    user_sub_token=$USER
    local_root=/var/www/$USER
    hide_ids=YES

    listen_address=0.0.0.0
    pasv_min_port=12000
    pasv_max_port=12100
    pasv_address=888.888.888.888 # My server IP
    listen_port=211
```

Remove everything from the file and add these lines instead

`auth required pam_pwdfile.so pwdfile /etc/ftpd.passwd`

`account required pam_permit.so`

Create the main user that will be used by the virtual users to authenticate:

`useradd --home /home/vsftpd --gid nogroup -m --shell /bin/false vsftpd`

Once that is done we can create our users/passwords file.

`htpasswd -cd /etc/ftpd.passwd helloftp`

Next, add the directories for the users since vsftpd will not create them automatically.

`mkdir /var/www/helloproject`

`chown vsftpd:nogroup /var/www/helloproject`

`chmod +w /var/www/helloproject`

Finally, start the vsftp daemon and set it to automatically start on system boot.

`systemctl start vsftpd && systemctl enable vsftpd`

Check the status to make sure the service is started:

`systemctl status vsftpd`

```
    ● vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server
    Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/vsftpd.service; enabled)
    Active: active (running) since Sat 2016-12-03 11:07:30 CST; 23min ago
    Main PID: 5316 (vsftpd)
    CGroup: /system.slice/vsftpd.service
    ├─5316 /usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd.conf
    ├─5455 /usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd.conf
    └─5457 /usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd.conf
```

Finally add firewall rules to access via cloud.

[image: Google Cloud Firewall Settings]

[image]

[image]

Later I have changed my IP from **0.0.0.0** for more restriction

Comment: It work's fine for me, but with some changes:

sudo nano /etc/pam.d/vsftpd
// replace everything with this:
auth required pam_pwdfile.so pwdfile /etc/ftpd.passwd
account required pam_permit.so
// end

Comment: "pasv_address=<external_instance_ip>" setting is mandatory to make it work from remote connections.
Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, It is possible to host an FTP server on Google Cloud. In fact, I wrote an in-depth blog about [How to set up an FTP server on Google Cloud](https://www.siteyaar.com/setup-ftp-server-on-google-cloud/).

If your VM is base on Linux then you have to use an application like vsftpd to set up an FTP server.

Here are the steps:

Step 1: Deploy a Virtual Instance on Google Cloud
Step 2: Open SSH terminal
Step 3: Installing VSFTPD
Step 4: Create a User
Step 5: Configure vsftpd.conf file
Step 6: Preparing an FTP Directory
Step 7: FTP/S or FTP over SSL setup (optional)
Step 8: Opening Ports in Google Cloud Firewall
Step 9: Test and Connect